# Is it ok to use <asp:SqlDataSource> multiple times in my .aspx file?

Tags: asp.net

I would like to ask if is it ok to use multiple `SqlDataSource` in asp.net. Apologies with my question, I'm just new at programming.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource9" runat="server" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT cdesc FROM [main] where [cmain]='O' and [cformat]='' order by cdesc"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:My_ConnectionString %>" /> 

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource10" runat="server" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT cdesc FROM [main] where [cmain]='Q' and [cformat]='' order by cdesc"
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:My_ConnectionString %>" />
```

Comment: why don't you try it and see? Multiple identical sources wouldn't make any sense, but there's no reason why multiple sources fetching different data would be a problem. Otherwise, it would make the pages pretty inflexible.

Comment: also if you have such a small difference between your queries, you can use parameters to vary the variable value (e.g. your `cmain` field) based on either user input, or your own scripts. You can easily google a tutorial about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can use multiple SqlDataSource on singe page.

But if you want to use connection to same table then instead of using multiple SqlDataSource, you can just link same SqlDataSource with multiple sources.